# Filter PySpark DataFrame content on Array value column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My schema is as follows:

```
DataFrame[record_id: string, months: array<decimal(2,0)>, max_amount: decimal(12,2)]
```

The data looks something like this:

```
+----------------+------------------+-------------------+
|       record_id|            months|         max_amount|
+----------------+------------------+-------------------+
|3535345345345343|   [4, 5, 6, 7, 9]|              17.33|
|3535345345345344|         [7, 8, 9]|               9.57|         
|3535345345345345|               [4]|               1.00| 
|3535345345345346|[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|              15.08|         
|3535345345345347|[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|              17.11|         
|3535345345345348|      [4, 5, 7, 9]|              12.99|         
|3535345345345349|[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|              16.95|         
|3535345345345340|   [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]|              12.99|        
|3535345345345311|[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|              12.99|         
|3535345345345542|[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|              12.99|       
+----------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

I would like to filter the data on the value present in the array under the months column (eg: get all the rows which has the month value 6 in the list). I tried the following, which works fine with string values:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

my_df.filter(sf.array_contains(my_df['months'], 6)).show()
```

But I get the following error in case of int array:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'array_contains(`months`, 6)' due to data type mismatch: Input to function array_contains should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [array<decimal(2,0)>, int].
```

I also tried using the `isin()`, but it isn't working. Do I have to modify the integer value passed as the second parameter in the `array_contains()` to make it work? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Your getting this error because 6 is a integer type and values inside the array is of decimal(2,0).
It should be like this my_df.filter(sf.array_contains(my_df['months'], sf.lit(6)."decimal(38,0)")).show()

Comment: It will probably work even by adding a dot like in here: my_df.filter(sf.array_contains(my_df['months'], 6.)).show()

Comment: @ggagliano I had tried with 6.0, but then it considers it as a 'double' datatype, and not decimal.

Comment: @code.gsoni that snippet is syntactically incorrect. I modified it, but it throws a `Column is not iterable` error.

Comment: Ok, I can't try it but something like this should do the trick my_df.filter('array_contains("months", decimal(6))').show()

Comment: @ggagliano Thank you! That worked after setting the decimal precision. But it was simpler to cast the 'months' from decimal to integer for using `filter()`.

Comment: in that case, post both the solutions as answer so everyone can find them easily ;)